# jinja url named routes escaped curly brace literal

Tags: javascript, python, escaping, braces, jinja2

I'm outputting the python named routes into a Urls JavaScript object like this:

```
var Urls = {
    ajaxCompanyList: "{%url data-company-list %}",
    ajaxCompanyDetail: "{%url data-company-detail '{0:companyId}' %}
    ...
```

I'm having a hard time trying to inject the company id into the named route to come out as

```
/company/{0:companyId}/detail
```

so that I can later use my messageFormatter function to replace `{0:companyId}`.

I've tried `{`, `{{`, `{{{`, `\{`, `&#123;` and nothing seems to work.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Coffin for the url tag or is that something you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Javascript escape sequence.

The code for `{` is `\u007b`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it results in the same "NoReverseMatch" error as the above efforts. :(